# Angularjs returns computer locale incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set my computer locale to 'en-AU'. And then I tried to get the computer locale using following angularjs services.

1. $window.navigator.language
2. $locale.id

But I am getting the answer as 'en-US'. Whatever change I do to my computer locale, the result not change. How can I get the locale correctly using angularjs?

Comment: This is a browser, not an angular.js problem.  $window.navigator just returns the underly window object.

Comment: Ok. So what can I do to get the locale correctly?